# handle timeout exception in loopj

Tags: android, android-async-http, loopj

I am having error in handling the timeout exception in `asynchttpclient`

```
@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

    closeProgressDialog();
    Log.e("DB", String.valueOf(error));
    Log.e("DB", String.valueOf(error.getCause() instanceof ConnectTimeoutException));
}
```

first log gives the response `cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /192.168.0.107:80 timed out`

while second log gives `null` or `false` 
I want to handle the timeout exception how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2nd log operation is based on

```
error.getCause()
```

which is null or not a `ConnectTimeoutException`, while within your first log operation you are directly using the `Throwable` given in method parameter.

Therefore, I would suggest to use the `error` and not `error.getCause()` to handle the `ConnectTimeoutException`.

```
Log.e("DB", String.valueOf(error instanceof ConnectTimeoutException)); // --> Should be true now
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to increase the timeout

```
client.setTimeout(15000);
```

then override all onFailure methods.

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable error, String content) {
 if ( error.getCause() instanceof ConnectTimeoutException ) {
    System.out.println("Connection timeout !");
 }
}
```

i hope this will solve the issue